# How to check whether a list is defined in Jinja2 ansible variable inside IF condition?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to iterate through a list using jinja2 template. I have the following variables defined

```
vars:
  app_name: testapp
  testapp_env_vars:
    - name: environment
      value: prod
    - name: type
      value: api
```

I want to check the following

1)  Whether the list "test_app_env_vars" is defined

2) if defined, then iterate through the key-value pair in the list using FOR loop and print the following

```
environment: prod
type: api
```

I tried using the following template, but its failing

```
{% if {{ app_name }}_env_vars is defined %}
{% for item in {{ app_name }}_env_vars %}
{{ item.name }}: {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

where "app_name" = "testapp" which is already defined in the `vars` section.

Any idea why `{ app_name }}_env_vars` inside `IF` condition is not evaluating to `testapp_env_vars`?

Comment: You cannot use Jinja2 expressions inside Jinja2 statements. To refer to a value with a dynamic variable name in Ansible, see the answer under the dup-target.

Comment: @techraf Thanks for the response. I want to do this within Jinja template file using "IF" condition, not from the Ansible tasks.

Comment: Yes. The same answer applies.

Comment: I added the following in the template file

    myvar: '{{ lookup('vars', {{ ocp_deployment_app }} + '_env_vars')}}'

But I am getting this error


    fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: myvar: '{{ lookup('vars', {{ ocp_deployment_app }} + '_env_vars')}}'\n"}

Comment: I already said, you cannot nest Jinja2 expressions inside Jinja2 expressions. Once you open `{{` you are writing Jinja2 code. And lookup  will fail on its own when variable does not exist; use `vars` as suggested at the top of the answer under the dup-target.

Comment: Could you please show me an example of doing this ?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a tutoring site, but here you are: `{% if vars[app_name + '_env_vars'] is defined %}`

Comment: @techraf Thanks, it worked.